# Derivation of the Geodesic Equation from Action Principle

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, general-relativity

So there is this derivation here [Geodesic Equation from Action Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Deriving_the_geodesic_equation_via_an_action) where the curvelength on some geometry is minimized. The derivation starts with some parameter $\lambda$ which gradually turns into the proper time $\tau$ -.-. Also at some point all of a sudden $\sqrt{-g_{\mu \nu} \, \frac{{\rm d}x^\mu}{{\rm d}\lambda} \frac{{\rm d}x^\nu}{{\rm d}\lambda}}$ is set to $1$ in the denominator, which is only legit if $\lambda=\tau$, but not for some arbitrary parameter $\lambda$. This is crucial, because if it would not be 1 (or constant), there would be another term arising after the partial integration which eventually leads to the equations of motion. So my question is, is the geodesic equation as typically given (top of the article with $s$) only valid if the velocity field $\frac{{\rm d}x^\mu}{{\rm d}\lambda}$ has unit (or constant) norm, but not for any arbitrary parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is not true? I'm not only talking about null rays.

Comment: Actually let me rephrase, I misinterpreted the statement because I was thinking of a completely different setting (Fermat's principle in relativity). It wasn't set to 1, but if the integrand has to vanish for arbirtrary $\delta$, then the value in the denominator doesn't matter. The numerator should be $0$. In very small parameter variations, that term in the denominator is a constant anyway.

Comment: Before this happens you need to partially integrate, which should include the denominator which is left out though...

Comment: If the localization argument isn't satisfying, then you can set the parameter to proper time before hand. Nothing in the derivation seems to change.

Comment: You mean set the parameter to proper time before, and then change it to another parameter after the equation for proper time has been derived? Also by localization argument you mean ``In very small parameter variations, that term in the denominator is a constant anyway.`` This is not true, because the constancy relevant here would be with respect to the parameter $\lambda$ and not with respect to the variation.

Comment: Pick $\lambda$ to be the proper time parameterization after the product rule happens. Then the argument runs the same if that happens before the integration by parts does.